# timed out waiting for the condition during Kubernetes Cluster Initialization with --control-plane-endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, high-availability, keepalived

Following the indications found here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/main/docs/ha-considerations.md#keepalived-and-haproxy I'm trying to initiate the very first control-plane-node , but I'm getting this error: `kubelet is not running or is unhealthy` . And in the output of journalct -xeu kubelet I get the error: `dial tcp: lookup vip.mycluster.local: Temporary failure in name resolution` . This happens only if initialize with `kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint vip.mycluster.local`
If I initalize the cluster with just `kubeadm init` I get no errors.

`journalct -xeu kubelet` output :

```
Nov 27 15:31:44 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 kubelet[33417]: E1127 15:31:44.505821   33417 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://vip.mycluster.local:6445/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1?timeout=10s\": dial tcp: lookup vip.mycluster.local: Temporary failure in name resolution" interval="7s"
Nov 27 15:31:44 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 kubelet[33417]: I1127 15:31:44.663579   33417 kubelet_node_status.go:70] "Attempting to register node" node="k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1"
Nov 27 15:31:44 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 kubelet[33417]: E1127 15:31:44.664815   33417 kubelet_node_status.go:92] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post \"https://vip.mycluster.local:6445/api/v1/nodes\": dial tcp: lookup vip.mycluster.local: Temporary failure in name resolution" node="k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1"
Nov 27 15:31:44 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 kubelet[33417]: E1127 15:31:44.957274   33417 eviction_manager.go:258] "Eviction manager: failed to get summary stats" err="failed to get node info: node \"k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1\" not found"
```

This is `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.conf` :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# cat /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg 
    # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/main/docs/ha-considerations.md#haproxy-configuration
    
    # /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Global settings
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    global
        log /dev/log local0
        log /dev/log local1 notice
        daemon
    
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
    # use if not designated in their block
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    defaults
        mode                    http
        log                     global
        option                  httplog
        option                  dontlognull
        option http-server-close
        option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
        option                  redispatch
        retries                 1
        timeout http-request    10s
        timeout queue           20s
        timeout connect         5s
        timeout client          20s
        timeout server          20s
        timeout http-keep-alive 10s
        timeout check           10s
    
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # apiserver frontend which proxys to the control plane nodes
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    frontend apiserver
        bind *:6445
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        default_backend apiserverbackend
    
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # round robin balancing for apiserver
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/main/docs/ha-considerations.md#bootstrap-the-cluster
    
    backend apiserverbackend
        option httpchk GET /healthz
        http-check expect status 200
        mode tcp
        option ssl-hello-chk
        balance     roundrobin
            server k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 aa.aaa.aaa.aa:8443 check
            server k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-2 bb.bbb.bbb.bbb:8443 check
            server k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-3 cc.ccc.ccc.ccc:8443 check
            # [...]
```

`keepalive`:

```
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# ls -lah /etc/keepalived/
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Nov 27 14:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 87 root root 4.0K Nov 27 11:32 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  672 Nov 27 13:56 check_apiserver.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  704 Nov 27 11:43 keepalived.conf
 root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# cat /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf 
    # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/main/docs/ha-considerations.md#keepalived-configuration
    # https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_22.04&p=keepalived&f=1
    
    ! /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
    ! Configuration File for keepalived
    global_defs {
        router_id LVS_DEVEL
        enable_script_security
    }
    vrrp_script check_apiserver {
      script "/etc/keepalived/check_apiserver.sh"
      interval 3
      weight -2
      fall 10
      rise 2
    }
    
    vrrp_instance VI_1 {
        state MASTER
        interface eth0
        virtual_router_id 51
        priority 101
        authentication {
            auth_type PASS
            auth_pass 42
        }
        virtual_ipaddress {
            10.0.0.30
        }
        track_script {
            check_apiserver
        }
    }


root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# cat /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf 
    # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/main/docs/ha-considerations.md#keepalived-configuration
    # https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_22.04&p=keepalived&f=1
    
    ! /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
    ! Configuration File for keepalived
    global_defs {
        router_id LVS_DEVEL
        enable_script_security
    }
    vrrp_script check_apiserver {
      script "/etc/keepalived/check_apiserver.sh"
      interval 3
      weight -2
      fall 10
      rise 2
    }
    
    vrrp_instance VI_1 {
        state MASTER
        interface eth0
        virtual_router_id 51
        priority 101
        authentication {
            auth_type PASS
            auth_pass 42
        }
        virtual_ipaddress {
            10.0.0.30
        }
        track_script {
            check_apiserver
        }
    }
    root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# cat /etc/keepalived/check_apiserver.sh 
    # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/main/docs/ha-considerations.md#keepalived-configuration
    # https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_22.04&p=keepalived&f=1
    
    #!/bin/sh
    
    errorExit() {
        echo "*** $*" 1>&2
        exit 1
    }
    
    APISERVER_DEST_PORT=6445
    APISERVER_VIP=10.0.0.30
    
    curl --silent --max-time 2 --insecure https://localhost/:${APISERVER_DEST_PORT}/ -o /dev/null || errorExit "Error GET https://localhost/:${APISERVER_DEST_PORT}/"
    if ip addr | grep -q ${APISERVER_VIP}; then
        curl --silent --max-time 2 --insecure https://${APISERVER_VIP}:${APISERVER_DEST_PORT}/ -o /dev/null || errorExit "Error GET https://${APISERVER_VIP}:${APISERVER_DEST_PORT}/"
    fi
```

`/etc/kubernetes/manifests/haproxy.yaml` :

```
 # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/main/docs/ha-
considerations.md#option-1-run-the-services-on-the-operating-system

  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Pod
  metadata:
    name: haproxy
    namespace: kube-system
  spec:
    containers:
    - image: haproxy:2.1.4
      name: haproxy
      livenessProbe:
        failureThreshold: 8
        httpGet:
          host: localhost
          path: /healthz
          port: 6445
          scheme: HTTPS
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
        name: haproxyconf
        readOnly: true
    hostNetwork: true
    volumes:
    - hostPath:
        path: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
        type: FileOrCreate
      name: haproxyconf
  status: {}
```

`/etc/kubernetes/manifests/keepalived.yaml` :

```
  # https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/main/docs/ha-
considerations.md#option-2-run-the-services-as-static-pods

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: keepalived
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - image: osixia/keepalived:2.0.17
    name: keepalived
    resources: {}
    securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add:
        - NET_ADMIN
        - NET_BROADCAST
        - NET_RAW
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/local/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
      name: config
    - mountPath: /etc/keepalived/check_apiserver.sh
      name: check
  hostNetwork: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
    name: config
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/keepalived/check_apiserver.sh
    name: check
```

This is the ouput of one of the initialization attempts (`DNS Address` of `k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1` = `aa.aaa.aaa.aa`) :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# sudo kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "aa.aaa.aaa.aa:6445" --upload-certs
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.28.4
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
W1127 16:47:19.353319   37423 checks.go:835] detected that the sandbox image "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6" of the container runtime is inconsistent with that used by kubeadm. It is recommended that using "registry.k8s.io/pause:3.9" as the CRI sandbox image.
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 aa.aaa.aaa.aa]
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 localhost] and IPs [aa.aaa.aaa.aa 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 localhost] and IPs [aa.aaa.aaa.aa 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
W1127 16:47:21.033530   37423 endpoint.go:57] [endpoint] WARNING: port specified in controlPlaneEndpoint overrides bindPort in the controlplane address
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
W1127 16:47:21.301458   37423 endpoint.go:57] [endpoint] WARNING: port specified in controlPlaneEndpoint overrides bindPort in the controlplane address
[kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
W1127 16:47:21.464421   37423 endpoint.go:57] [endpoint] WARNING: port specified in controlPlaneEndpoint overrides bindPort in the controlplane address
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
W1127 16:47:21.572446   37423 endpoint.go:57] [endpoint] WARNING: port specified in controlPlaneEndpoint overrides bindPort in the controlplane address
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.
Here is one example how you may list all running Kubernetes containers by using crictl:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'crictl --runtime-endpoint unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock logs CONTAINERID'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Looking for hints